# Haskell remove parenthesis for a tuple

Tags: list, haskell

I'm a beginner in Haskell, and this is a question for an assignment. 
I'm pretty much done the problem, but I can't figure out how to remove the parenthesis that is surrounding a tuple that I calculated.

```
get_balance_partition :: Int -> [([Int], [Int])] -> (Int, ([Int], [Int]))
get_balance_partition min (x:xs)
    | null xs && difference_partitions x == min = (min, x)
    | null xs = (min, ([], []))
    | difference_partitions x == min = (min, x)
    | otherwise = get_balance_partition min xs
```

This is a helper function for working code, and I use it like this :

```
get_balance_partition 2 (two_partitions [7, 4, 3, 6, 10])

output : (2,([7,4,3],[6,10]))
```

I want to get rid of the parenthesis surrounding the pair of partitions so that the result,

```
 (2,([7,4,3],[6,10]))
```

looks like

```
 (2,[7,4,3],[6,10])
```

How can I get rid of the parenthesis when the pair of partitions is stored in x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no standard functions that work on triples, you have to write them yourself.

```
munge :: (a,(b,c)) -> (a,b,c)
munge (x,(y,z)) = (x,y,z)

munge (get_balance_partition 2 (two_partitions [7, 4, 3, 6, 10]))
```

Or anonymously as a lambda

```
(\(x,(y,z)) -> (x,y,z)) (get_balance_partition 2 (two_partitions [7, 4, 3, 6, 10]))
```

Another way is to modify your definition to match on the tuple in the list directly:

```
get_balance_partition :: Int -> [([Int], [Int])] -> (Int, ([Int], [Int]))
get_balance_partition min ((x,y):xs)
   ...
```

And use `(x,y)` instead of `x` everywhere, then you can return e.g. `(min, x, y)` in the first case, and similarly in other cases.

Comment: you beat me to it

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't think of simply changing x into (x,y). I'll accept your answer when the timer lets me.